# bootstrap - Align table data with each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can i make this align with each other. i'm using bootstrap table classes and CSS only. and trying to figure this thing out. my take is it's changing depends on the width of the text.

[image]

This is my code so far and it's inside an accordion btw.  :

```
        <table class = "table"> 
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <thead>
                            <h1>DIMENSIONS</h1>
                        </thead>

                        <tr>
                            <td class = "spec-header">  
                                    <h2>Overall(Length x Width x Height)</h2>
                            </td>

                            <td class = "spec-content"> 
                                   <p>4,410 x 1,700 x 1,1475</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class = "spec-header">  
                                    <h2>Wheelbase</h2>
                            </td>

                            <td class = "spec-content"> 
                                   <p>2,550mm</p>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class = "spec-header">  
                                    <h2>Tread(Front/Rear)</h2>
                            </td>

                            <td class = "spec-content"> 
                                   <p>1,475/1460</p>

                            </td>
                        </tr>


                </tr>       
            </tbody>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: @kerrin sorry im using 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `vertical-align:middle;`

```
.table>tbody>tr>td,
.table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td,
.table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td,
.table>thead>tr>th{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

example [here](https://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/mBpdPL)

Answer (score 1):

Add your own class to override the bootstrap selector:

```
.table tbody>tr>td.vert-align
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And then add it to your tds

```
<td class="spec-content vert-align"></td>
```